# Env variable not found by R in Azure Pipeline

Tags: r, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to convert my Travis-based tests to Azure Pipelines, and I'm running into a problem where R doesn't seem to pick up an environment variable.

Here is the yaml:

```
trigger:
- master

variables:
- group: GH
- name: R_LIBS_USER
  value: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/R/library'
- name: containerImage
  value: rocker/rstudio:latest

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

container: rocker/rstudio:latest

steps:
- script: |
    echo 'options(repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org")' > ~/.Rprofile
    mkdir -p ${R_LIBS_USER}
  displayName: 'Setup R library directory'

- bash: |
    Rscript -e "install.packages(c('remotes', 'rcmdcheck'))"  <-- problem here
    Rscript -e "remotes::install_deps(dependencies=TRUE)"
  displayName: 'Installing package dependencies'

- bash: |
    Rscript -e "rcmdcheck::rcmdcheck(args = '--no-manual', error_on = 'error', check_dir = 'check')"
  displayName: 'Checking package'
```

The problem is in the `bash` step where I install the remotes and rcmdcheck packages, and then run `install_deps`. For some reason R doesn't see the R_LIBS_USER variable, which should expand to something like `/__w/1/R/library`. Because of this, it tries to install to the site-wide location `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library`, which fails because this directory is not user-writeable.

What's happening here?

Comment: Try to check if the folder is create when you use the command `mkdir -p ${R_LIBS_USER}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever reason, R just can't see the environment variable `R_LIBS_USER`. What finally worked for me was editing the `~/.Rprofile` config file to include the user library directory:

```
steps:
- script: |
    echo 'options(repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org")' > ~/.Rprofile
    echo ".libPaths(c('$R_LIBS_USER', .libPaths()))" >> ~/.Rprofile
    mkdir -p $(R_LIBS_USER)
  displayName: 'Setup R library directory'
```

Now I just need to figure out how to avoid reinstalling several megabytes of dependencies on each run....

Comment: Check out the Cache Beta tasks: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/CacheBetaV0

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/blob/35e162aea081dee856a000a03a08951df6c275bf/design/pipeline-caching.md